# Wayland Touchpad Jumping - Motion Treshold?

Tags: debian, gnome, touchpad, wayland, thinkpad

I just switched from Ubuntu 17.10 to Debian Buster Sid, using GNOME 3.26.2.

I'm using a Thinkpad T430. See below for more information on my touchpad.

```
$ grep -B 5 mouse /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event1 
--
[...]
```

The problem is that **two finger scrolling is very unprecise due to jumping**. While I'm scrolling everything works fine, but as soon as I'm lifting up my fingers to stop, the page just randomly jumps or scrolls a bit randomly up or down. I never experienced such behaviour under Ubuntu.

I suspect that the motion threshold is simply to low, so that my lifting figures are detected as another scroll.

All solutions for similar issues that I found requiere to edit the conf file which, as I found out, isn't used under Wayland.

So I checked gsettings but didn't find a proper key:

```
$ gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad
send-events
natural-scroll
tap-to-click
two-finger-scrolling-enabled
left-handed
click-method
speed
tap-and-drag
edge-scrolling-enabled
disable-while-typing
```

How to fix this?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to debug and recalibrate the touchpad as described in Wayland [Touchpad pressure-based touch detection](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad_pressure.html). Basically, you run a libinput utility and press on the touchpad to see what threshold you should use:

```
sudo libinput measure touchpad-pressure
```

You then try that value out

```
sudo libinput measure touchpad-pressure --touch-thresholds=10:8
```

and finally create an overriding hwdb entry, such as `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/99-touchpad-pressure.hwdb` with an entry matching your keyboard, and the override:

```
libinput:name:*SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad:dmi:*
 LIBINPUT_ATTR_PRESSURE_RANGE=10:8
```

Comment: Gives me "Error: device does not have ABS_MT_PRESSURE".
These are the touchpad props
Device:           SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event1
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             76x45mm
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   none
Rotation:         n/a

Comment: So the pressure detection must be fixed in the device and you cannot change it. The only solution would be to write your own program that read the raw events from the device and tried to detect and suppress the spurious scroll movements. That would not be easy. You could also try using the edge scroll; perhaps it is less buggy.

Comment: @meuh: I have an identical problem with a Lenovo T520 and the same error trying your suggestion. If it is fixed in the hardware, then howcome windows 7 (previously) and windows 10 both **don't** have a problem with this?

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't know how Windows does anything, but manufacturers needing to run that system are obliged for their certification to make their hardware compatible with what that software expects, or to provide drivers to interface with it, beyond any potential international norms and specifications, which is all that Linux has to work with.